# How to sort a Magento Plugin to first in Frontend

Tags: magento

I have 4 payment modules active in Frontend.
I want to sort Module ABC (Now in 3rd position) to be first.

I tried following code in **system.xml** file

```
<label>Module ABC</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>000</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
```

But its moving to second position, not first

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<label>Module ABC</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>000</sort_order>
<show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
```

Comment: It worked. Also I found the one which I install the last gets sorted FIRST